# Set ListBox CheckBox Content dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a WPF user control which is a `ListBox` that contains `CheckBox`es.

```
<UserControl x:Class="AC.CodA.WPF.UserControls.CheckedListBox"
             x:Name="Root"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:Background="White">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox BorderThickness="0"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ItemsSource}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Focusable"
                            Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                              Content="{Binding Item}">
                    </CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Separator />
        <CheckBox x:Name="DeSelectAll"
                  Content="Select / deselect all"
                  Checked="DeSelectAll_Checked"
                  Unchecked="DeSelectAll_Unchecked" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I'm using this control at another place:

```
<GroupBox Header="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Header, FallbackValue=Header}">
    <user:CheckedListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Companies}" />
</GroupBox>
```

At this place, the `Companies` property is an `ObservableCollection<CheckedListBoxItem<Company>>`.

`CheckedListBoxItem` is a class with `bool IsChecked` property and generic `T Item` property.

Now, `T Item` can be anything. At this point I have this property set as the `Content` of the `CheckBox` but most times this results in something ambiguous like `AC.CodA.Scripting.Shared.Company`.

Is there a way to set the `CheckBox` `Content` outside of the user control? Something like this with `CheckBoxContent`:

```
<GroupBox Header="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Header, FallbackValue=Header}">
    <user:CheckedListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Companies}" CheckBoxContent="{Binding Item.Name}" />
</GroupBox>
```

and inside my object this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
          Content="{Binding CheckBoxContent}">
</CheckBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `CheckBoxContent` [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/custom-dependency-properties?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) to your `UserControl`'s code-behind file:

```
public partial class CheckedListBox : UserControl
{
    ...

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckBoxContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CheckBoxContent), typeof(object),
            typeof(CheckedListBox));

    public object CheckBoxContent
    {
        get { return GetValue(CheckBoxContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CheckBoxContentProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

...and bind to it in your XAML markup:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
          Content="{Binding CheckBoxContent,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: Tnx for the reply. I've done this like you suggested but how would I now fill in this `CheckBoxContent` when using the `CheckedListBox`? Take a class `Company` for example with a property `Name`. I've tried the following but the content is empty: `<user:CheckedListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=Companies}" CheckBoxContent="{Binding Name}" />`.

Comment: Does it work if you set the property to a constant string value, e.g: `CheckBoxContent="test"`? Then the binding to `Name` fails.

Comment: Tnx for the help but the project has moved on and decided to use another approach. Sorry for wasting your time.